# kubernetes logs for service or deployment

Tags: kubernetes, logging, service

I am having real trouble understanding how I am suppose to debug my current situation. I have followed the setup instructions from `https://docs.substra.org/en/stable/contributing/getting-started.html#`
There is a backend service which was created as a ClusterIP, and therefore can not be accessed from the host.
I created a load balancer for this purpose. using the command

```
kubectl expose deployment deployment_name --port=8000 --target-port=8000 \
        --name=lb_service --type=LoadBalancer
```

However, the attempt to access the backend service failed when I use the `LoadBalancer Ingress` ip and `NodePort` port with a connection timeout. I like to see the relevant logs to check where the problem occurred. However, apparently `kubectl logs` service only shows logs for pods, whereas the load balancer, according to the `kubectl expose` command is attached to the deployment. Therefore, I am not able to see any logs related either to the load balancer service, or the deployment component.
When I looked at the pod which is supposed to be hosting the deployment, the log showed no error.
Can someone point out where do I look for logs that can debug this failed connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look at the ingress logs, se this page from the documentation: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/.

Comment: the document still talks about applying kubectl logs only to pods. But I am able to find the error messages that way. So I will close this post.

Comment: Well the ingress process also runs in a pod so I don't think you will find logs in any other location.

Answer (score 0):

it is true that you can only get logs from pods. However, that is sufficient to see the relevant error messages.